# Xcode 7.3.1 - Can't properly setup AWS

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, installation, cocoapods

A year ago I had a project where I was using AWS. I forget exactly how it worked but it involved a BridgingHeader and no use of Frameworks.

I came back to this project today and none of the AWS stuff was working. I deleted all AWS/pod related files, got rid of the BridgingHeader reliance, cleaned the project, and proceeded to follow the pod-based instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html

However, the project still doesn't recognize any of the AWS libraries (getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier AWS...").

I saw a post by someone that suggested simply putting "import Framework" at the top of the files that use that Framework, but this doesn't work (it doesn't recognize AWSS3 when I put "import AWSS3", for example).

Then I saw advice that suggested figuring out the correct "Framework/Header/Library Search Paths" and so I created a brand new project, copied the podfile, and ran pod install. In this new project I am getting the error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestProj-gmhzshcpuyuvaffaocakhunyepaw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSAutoScaling'

for each of the AWS libraries.

When I go into the target build settings, I see that the Framework Search Paths have strings relating to the AWS libraries, but when I delete them I then get the error "ld: Framework not found AWSAutoScaling".

I tried giving the direct path to the respective folders but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you checked both the app and app.test targets while you were deleting the paths?

Comment: Yeah, I just get the "ld: Framework not found AWSAutoScaling" error

Comment: I tried deleting the "Runpath Search Paths" too, to no avail

Comment: Add `$(inherited)` and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by opening the .xcworkspace file instead of the the .xcodeproj file.